# Yii how to redirect to slug link form controller?

Tags: php, yii

I have a forum, in a URL as  : http://example.com/fourm/

that using slug in url, like : http://example.com/fourm/a-category-name

On the page of category, there is a form to add topic,
which user can input a title, which will also make it into slug for SEO
let's say the title slug is "some-topic-title"

so the topic url will be : http://example.com/fourm/a-category-name/some-topic-title

My question is, what should I input in the `redirect()` function ?

```
public function actionCreate(){
    if(isset($_POST['Forum'])){
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Forum'];
        if($model->save()){
            $this->redirect( ????? );
        }
    }
```

The controller for display Topic content is "ForumPostController" and inside it the actionIndex is like this :

```
public function actionIndex($cateSlug, $TopicSlug){
    $model = new ForumPost;
    $cate_id  = ForumCate::model()->getCateIdBySlug():
    $topic_id = Forum::model()->getTopicIdBySlug():
    $model = $model->selectPost($cate_id, $topic_id);
    $this->render('index',array(
        'model'=>$model;
    ));
}
```

I know I can make the URL to redirect, but is better for make it in the "yii way".
the action above is for handling user-enter-link, should I make another action for receive the redirect? or any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->redirect($this->createUrl('index', array('cateSlug' => $model->cate_slug)));
```

reference here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail

Answer (score 0):

You can add an array as a parameter to the redirect function. The first element of the array should be the controller/action, and all other elements are the parameters. Reference here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail

So this will work for you:

```
$this->redirect(array(
        'forumPostController/index',
        'cateSlug' => $model->cate_slug,
        'topicSlug' => $model->topicSlug,
));
```

**Note:** Be sure to generate the slugs in your model's beforeSave method, so after the $model->save() where you redirect the user, the slugs will be available, and you can redirect properly.

You don't need another action to handle the redirect, just redirect where you render the forum topic *(so it's good as it is now)*